# Access to ServletContext from PushStrategy

Tags: jetty, spdy

I try to implement a custom PushStrategy, which is an API related to server push support of SPDY protocol inside Jetty.

I implement the following method:

```java
public Set<String> apply(Stream stream, Fields requestHeaders, Fields responseHeaders);
```

However I need to access the ServletContext inside the method call but I don't know how I can access it.

I'm investigating a way to inject the WebAppContext in jetty.xml:

```xml
<New id="pushStrategy" class="spdy.MyPushStrategy">
    <Set name="webAppContext">
        <Ref id="..." />
    </Set>
</New>
```

The problem is that this configuration step is in the Server block declared in jetty.xml:

```xml
<Configure id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">....</Configure>
```

while WebAppContext is configured in jetty-web.xml

```xml
<Configure id="WebAppContext" class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
```

I don't know how to refer any existing WebAppContext ID in this file.

Here is my maven plugin config:

```xml
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty-version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <stopPort>8888</stopPort>
                <stopKey>quit</stopKey>
                <jvmArgs>
                    -Xbootclasspath/p:${settings.localRepository}/org/mortbay/jetty/npn/npn-boot/${npn-version}/npn-boot-${npn-version}.jar
                </jvmArgs>
                <webAppConfig>
                    <jettyEnvXml>${basedir}/src/main/config/jetty-web.xml</jettyEnvXml>
                </webAppConfig>
                <jettyXml>${basedir}/src/main/config/jetty.xml</jettyXml>
                <contextPath>/</contextPath>
            </configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a `WebAppContext` via an XML file, such as what is described in the [Configuring a Specific WebApp Deployment](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/configuring-specific-webapp-deployment.html).

You can configure an `id` attribute for that particular webapp's `<Configure>` element.

Example:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN"
      "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_0.dtd">

<Configure id="myapp1" class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
  <Set name="contextPath">/wiki</Set>
  <Set name="war">/opt/myapp/myapp.war</Set>
</Configure>
```

Then you can use the Jetty XML notation you described to reference that particular webapp.

```xml
<New id="pushStrategy" class="spdy.MyPushStrategy">
  <Set name="webAppContext">
    <Ref id="myapp1" />
  </Set>
</New>
```

Now, back to your more specific concern, access to the `ServletContext` from the `PushStrategy` implementation.

That cannot be done from a `PushStrategy` implementation, as it is too high-level in the layering of the TLS -> SPDY (with PushStrategy) -> Connector -> Connection -> HTTP -> Request -> Handlers -> WebAppContext -> ServletContext -> Servlet.

You might be able to split up the behavior though.

Create a `CustomPushFilter` that your Servlet context has, it has the logic on what you want to associate for the push, done via a custom response header.  Then your `CustomPushStrategy` could look for those response headers to know how to associate those extra resources.  Bonus with this approach is that your Servlets could even automatically add resources for push based on servlet specific knowledge.

Comment: This does not works. My object is created in jetty.xml and it's referencing a webapp configured in jetty-web.xml! See the updated topic

Comment: The spdy.MyPushStrategy instance has its setter called but a null value is specified as parameter.

Comment: is this an open source PushStrategy that we can see somewhere?

Comment: Sure: http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/spdy/server/http/ReferrerPushStrategy.html

Comment: Implementation out of the box are ususally based on the same technique accross servers (jetty, undertow, etc): collecting resources to push with the "referer" header of HTTP requests sent by the browser to load statics

Comment: heh. i was referring to *your* custom PushStrategy. :)  [I would hope that I know the official implementation](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/commits?author=joakime).

Comment: ahahah sorry I did'nt want to offend you. I'm just collecting information before [writting my own implementation](https://github.com/wuic/wuic/issues/158). Bad news: I don't think to have time for it before Feb. But good news: the code will be on github :)

Comment: Joakim, as the community moved to HTTP/2, I focused on the new protocol support. A user can install a [filter](https://github.com/wuic/wuic/blob/wuic-0.5.x-snapshot/wuic/servlet/src/main/java/com/github/wuic/servlet/HtmlParserFilter.java#L312) from my project to push resources associated to the filtered page. I'm working on an abstract API that can support server specific API easily (at least for undertow and [jetty](https://github.com/wuic/wuic-extensions/tree/wuic-0.5.x-snapshot/http2-jetty/src/main)).